# How can I write a method that accepts a lambda expression where the number of parameters to the lambda expression is unknown?

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to write a method that accepts a lambda expression.  The number of input arguments to this lambda expression will vary in my code.  The number of input arguments will determine what happens in the method body.

Pseudo-code follows:

```
private void foo(Expression e)
{
   // I don't know what parameter type foo should accept -- please suggest!
   double a, b, c;

   int count = e.NumberOfArguments;

   double[] args;
   if(count == 1) args = new[]{a};
   else if(count == 2) args = new[]{ a, b };
   ... and so on...

   e.Invoke(args);
}

private void goo()
{
   // called as follows:
   foo(x => true);
   foo((x,y) => true);
   foo((x,y,z) => true);
}
```

I don't really know what object foo should accept as a parameter (I'm guessing probably an Expression?) and I'm also not sure how to obtain the number of parameters in the lambda expression as well as invoke it.

Additionally, it would be a bonus if e could be invoked by passing an array with a variable number of elements.

**Additional context:**

I have a time series object.  When foo is invoked with N parameters, I wish to use the time series together with it's 1st, 2nd, 3rd ... (N-1)-th derivative to generate a result (eg. bool).  There could be instances when I need to use only the time series itself -- in this case I would only supply a single parameter; there are other situations where I wish to generate a result using the time series, it's first derivative as well as it's second derivative -- in this case, I would supply 3 parameters.  And so on...

I hope that makes more sense.  I am also open to more elegant ways to implement this requirement.

Comment: how about using `params` as part of the expression maybe?

Comment: I had the same intuition but did not manage to flesh it out.  Any help?

Comment: @JohnC Work on the parameter of `foo` first, because `foo(x => true)` won't be a valid call if the parameter is simply `Expression`. The answer to your main question heavily depends on what you settle on for the parameter type.

Comment: @hvd Please change the parameter type as you deem fit!  I am at a lost what the parameter type should be.

Comment: What is the intended usage of `foo`? `goo` example does not make a much sense, if you know the expression and arguments, why not invoke it yourself. A more realistic example is needed.

Comment: Why do you need such a method? Maybe there is a more efficient way than expressions to solve the problem.

Comment: @IvanStoev Context added to question.

Comment: Still don't see the use case for `foo` - it just complicates the things that can easily be solved in a normal way, and the function itself seems to be not doing anything useful - I mean, there is no logic, everything needs to be passed by the caller, so what is the expected benefit - type inference or ? Why don't you provide a code example with a few cases described in the *additional context* section - input and intended `foo` calls

Comment: @IvanStoev foo will clean the data (substantial work here) and compute the required derivatives of the time series.

Comment: Sorry, but this to me is a typical XY problem. Good luck.

Comment: What is a typical XY problem?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it compiles and runs, but I'm not sure I'd want it in *my* codebase:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal sealed class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            goo();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        private static void foo(LambdaExpression e)
        {
            double a, b, c;
            a = 1.0;
            b = 1.0;
            c = 1.0;
            bool result = false;
            int count = e.Parameters.Count;
            if (count == 1)
            {
                result = (bool)e.Compile().DynamicInvoke(a);
            }
            else if (count == 2)
            {
                result = (bool)e.Compile().DynamicInvoke(a,b);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        private static void goo()
        {
            foo((Expression<Func<double, bool>>) (x => true));
            foo((Expression<Func<double, double, bool>>) ((x, y) => true));
            foo((Expression<Func<double, double, double, bool>>) ((x, y, z) => true));
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm also not sure whether it'll be the solution to your actual problem. (Also, insert usual caveats about complete lack of error checking, etc)

Comment: That looks close to what I was trying to accomplish, but can this be done without the cast of the lambd expression when calling foo?  Also, any way to involve 'params' in the invocation of the LambdaExpression e?

Comment: @JohnC - I tried without the casts but then the compiler doesn't have enough information to work out the types of `x`, `y` and `z` when compiling `goo`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Damien's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever) excelent answer, I'd refactor the code to make it a little more useful.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TestFoo();
}

private static Tuple<bool, Exception> Foo<T>(LambdaExpression expression, out T result, params object[] parameters)
{
    bool succesful = false;
    result=default(T);
    Exception invokeException = null;

    if (expression.Parameters.Count == parameters.Length)
    {
        try
        {
            result = (T)expression.Compile().DynamicInvoke(parameters);
            succesful = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            invokeException = e;
        }
    }

    return new Tuple<bool, Exception>(succesful, invokeException);
}

private static void TestFoo()
{
    bool result;
    double sum;

    var succesful = Foo((Expression<Func<bool>>)(() => true), out result);
    Debug.Assert(succesful.Item1);
    Debug.Assert(result);
    Debug.Assert(succesful.Item2 == null);

    succesful = Foo((Expression<Func<double, bool>>)(x => x == 1.0), out result, 1.0);
    Debug.Assert(succesful.Item1);
    Debug.Assert(result);
    Debug.Assert(succesful.Item2 == null);

    succesful = Foo((Expression<Func<double, double, double>>)((x, y) => x + y), out sum, 2.0, 3.0);
    Debug.Assert(succesful.Item1);
    Debug.Assert(sum == 5);
    Debug.Assert(succesful.Item2 == null);

    succesful = Foo((Expression<Func<double, double, double>>)((x, y) => x + y), out sum, 2.0, new object());
    Debug.Assert(!succesful.Item1);
    Debug.Assert(succesful.Item2 is ArgumentException);

}
```

This should work reasonably well.

Comment: Is there a way to not have to cast when using foo if I know that the Func will take double input parameters and produce a bool output?

Answer (score 0):

I think to make this maintainable, it makes more sense to make `foo` overloaded. And at that point, you can easily introduce custom logic for handling the number of parameters, because you know exactly how many parameters you have.

```
// forward to main implementation
private void foo(Func<bool> e)
{
   foo((a, b, c) => e());
}

// forward to main implementation
private void foo(Func<double, bool> e)
{
   foo((a, b, c) => e(a));
}

// forward to main implementation
private void foo(Func<double, double, bool> e)
{
   foo((a, b, c) => e(a, b));
}

// the main implementation
private void foo(Func<double, double, double, bool> e)
{
   double a, b, c;
   ...
   e(a, b, c);
}

private void goo()
{
   foo(() => true);
   foo(x => true);
   foo((x,y) => true);
   foo((x,y,z) => true);
}
```

Note that I'm not using `Expression` types here since your question talks about invoking it directly (instead of e.g. passing it to a LINQ provider), but the same basic approach would work just as well for `Expression<Func<bool>>`, `Expression<Func<double, bool>>`, ... overloads.

Comment: I agree using overloads makes the problem trivial.  However, I was hoping for a succinct all-in-one solution using lambda or expressions (and in the process learn something).  Efficiency isn't my focus for now.

Comment: @JohnC If you want your call syntax to work, you need overloads anyway though, there's no way around that.